# sending a 'const char*' parameter to a function that receives 'const char* &'

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

why is this not OK?

```
void func(const char* &pointer){...}


//in main
const char* mainPointer = "a word";
func(mainPointer);
```

my intention is to send a pointer to a function, that changes it(the pointer) but doesn't change the chars it is pointing  to.

Comment: That should work - http://ideone.com/93Zuo and it's OK to use.

Comment: Are you potentially compiling as C and not C++ ?

Comment: no.I'm compilimg in c++. the error I get it: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'const char *&'

Comment: @kakush: show your complete program. In the error message, I think the compiler is saying that you're supplying an rvalue expression of type `const char*`, not just the name of a variable.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: OK.. thats weired. I actually was trying to call the function with func(mainPointer+1) and that didn't work, but this: func(mainPointer) worked. why? ( @steve my code is a bit complicated..so I didn't want to write the whole thing

Comment: @kakush: you can't take a reference to `mainPointer+1`. It's a value resulting from a computation, and it doesn't necessarily have an address in memory. Even if you could modify it, you wouldn't be modifying `mainPointer`, which is what you expected, you'd be modifying some pointer containing the value of `mainPointer+1`. So the C++ standard forbids a normal `&` reference from binding to an rvalue.

Comment: Because mainPointer+1 is not a reference to another object/var. it is strictly a value (a value that points to something, granted, but still a value). Think of refs as synonymous for the thing you're passing in right down to the address.

Comment: oh thanks! dont know what I was thinking :)

Comment: Heh. not a single one of us that can't claim the same. No worries.

Comment: @kakush NRGH! Why leaving out **exactly this** part of the code? I understand you wanted to keep the example concise, but at least try to reproduce the **single code line** that threw the error (along with the error message, of course) instead of some simplified **non-erroneous** code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code (MS Visual C++ 2010) shows that it is perfectly possible and works. The output is: "World!"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void func(const char*& ptr) 
{
    ptr += 6;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const char* Ptr = "Hello World!";
    func(Ptr);
    cout << Ptr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in contrast to Null Voids code, we do modify the pointer within func here.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly OK. Infact it works like a charm.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;



void func(const char* &pointer)
{
  cout<<" \n "<<pointer<<"\n";
}


int main()
{
    const char* mainPointer = "a word";
    func(mainPointer);

    cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
 a word

Press any key to continue
```

Compile output:

```
Compiling...
this.cpp
Linking...

this.exe - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: Reading the question, I guess you should change the pointer within func to demonstrate the point.